# error delcare cursor mysql stored procedure

Tags: mysql, sql, cursor, procedure

i have the next stored procedure, i have created other procedures in mysql before with cursor but i this, mysql send me an error: the procedure is the next:

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS systm;

delimiter //

CREATE PROCEDURE systm()
BEGIN
    DECLARE bdone INT;
    DECLARE var1 VARCHAR(250);
    DECLARE var2 VARCHAR(250);
    DECLARE puntero VARCHAR(5);


    SET @query = CONCAT('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `wg_init` (
                         `id` int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
                         `nombre` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
                         `valor` varchar(500) NOT NULL,
                          PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
                        ) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;');

    PREPARE stmt FROM @query;
    EXECUTE stmt;
    DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;

    DECLARE curs CURSOR FOR SELECT `nombre` FROM `wg_datos`;

    DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET bDone = 1;

    OPEN curs;

    SET bdone = 0;
    REPEAT
      FETCH curs INTO puntero;

      SET @slt = CONCAT( 'SELECT nombre,valor INTO var1,var2 FROM wg_datos WHERE id =',puntero,'and nombre NOT LIKE "%descripcion%" ' ); 
      PREPARE stmt FROM @slt;
      EXECUTE stmt;
      DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;

      SET @query = CONCAT('INSERT INTO wg_init(nombre,valor) VALUES (',var1,',',var2,' ) ');

      PREPARE stmt FROM @query;
      EXECUTE stmt;
      DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;

    UNTIL bdone END REPEAT;
    CLOSE curs;
END
//

delimiter ;

CALL systm();
```

the procedure it's easy, it have to do the next:

First, create a table, after, another query gets the id with a select fetching by a cursor, by each row, it selects (nombre,valor) from the id obtained by the fetch cursor and executes a insert in the new table with the values obtained before. it's easy but mysql sends me an error like that:

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
near 'DECLARE curs CURSOR FOR SELECT `nombre` FROM `wg_datos`;

DECLARE CONT' at line 15
```

i have tried to execute the query:

```
SELECT nombre FROM wg_datos
```

and works fine.

can anybody help me?

Comment: MySQL is very strict about the order of statements in a stored program... "DECLARE is permitted only inside a BEGIN ... END compound statement and must be at its start, before any other statements.

Declarations must follow a certain order. Cursor declarations must appear before handler declarations. Variable and condition declarations must appear before cursor or handler declarations."  http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/declare.html  "Variable declarations must appear before cursor or handler declarations." http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/declare-local-variable.html

Comment: thants i got it, but now if i executed it tells me this error: undeclared variable var1, and var1 is declared at the begin. i'm doing anything worng??

Comment: Check the dynamic SELECT statement that includes `INTO var1,var2` ... the context of that statement doesn't include the procedure variables. Those procedure variables are not in scope in the dynamic SELECT. I'm utterly confused. Firstly, why you need a cursor loop (rather than just handling the entire set in one fell swoop), and if you absolutely need to process this RBAR (row-by-agonizing-row) in a slow cursor loop, why you need a dynamic statement, why not just return "`valor`" in the cursor that is already retrieving "`nombre`".

Comment: i need to insert in `wg_init` the data of `wg_datos` except the values that contains %descripcion%  sure if its possible to execute this in one query but i would try this method to practise. how can i do to include var1,var2 the context of that statement? can you show me any example? thanks

Comment: Why would you want to practice using a cursor when you should not be using cursors? If you aren't a DBA there is no reason why you should ever need to write a cursor.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, I'm not understanding why you need a cursor loop to process the set RBAR (row-by-agonizing-row), why you don't just accomplish this in one fell swoop.

Then again, it's not clear why you are fetching `nombre` from `wg_datos`, and then using that value in an equality predicate against the `id` column.

And the value of `nombre` is being fetched into a VARCHAR(5) variable. We don't see the datatype of `id` is in `wg_datos`.

It's not clear what this stored procedure is supposed to achieve, and I think the issues go much deeper than syntax issues with the order of DECLARE statements.

If we do a cursor loop, and fetch the value of `nombre` into a VARCHAR(5), and then use that value in a comparison against the `id` column...  the SELECT ... INTO ... is going to throw an error if more than one row is returned...

It all just seems very bizarre. It looks like the procedure is going to be processing a set similar to the one returned by a query like this:

```
SELECT v.nombre
     , v.valor
  FROM wg_datos i
  JOIN wg_datos v
    ON v.id = SUBSTRING(i.nombre,1,5)
   AND v.nombre NOT LIKE '%descripcion%'
```

The difference with the procedure, of course, is if the `SELECT ... INTO ...` doesn't return a row, the procedure is still going to process an `INSERT` statement.

Very weird.

Aside from the bizzare code, I haven't a clue about what this procedure is actually supposed to accomplish.

---

If the intent is to simply copy rows from `wg_datos` into `wg_init`, excluding rows that include the string "descripcion" in nombre, and assign new auto_increment `id` values to the rows in wg_init...

```
 CREATE PROCEDURE systm()
 BEGIN
    SET @query = CONCAT('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `wg_init` (
                     `id` int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
                     `nombre` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
                     `valor` varchar(500) NOT NULL,
                      PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
                    ) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;');

    PREPARE stmt FROM @query;
    EXECUTE stmt;
    DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;

    INSERT INTO wg_init(nombre,valor)
    SELECT d.nombre
         , d.valor
      FROM wg_datos d
     WHERE d.nombre NOT LIKE '%descripcion%'
    ;

 END$$

 DELIMITER ;
```